# Left outer join with a condition

Tags: sql

I haven't been able to confirm an answer to this question anywhere... I have some code like this (PL/SQL):

```
select 
    tbl1.ID
    , tbl1.col1
    , tbl1.col2
    , tbl2.col1
from 
    table1 tbl1
    , table2 tbl2
where
    (tbl1.ID = tbl2.ID(+)
    and tbl2.col2 = 12345)
```

I'm left outer joining to table2 (tbl2 could have NULLs), indicated by the "(+)" notation, but I also need to filter by tbl2.col2 = 12345. Is it still a left outer join if I'm adding that condition, or is there a way to specify that tbl2.col2 = 12345 should also be a left join? In other words, I'm concerned that I might need to do something like "tbl2.col2 = 12345(+)" but I'm not sure either.

Thanks for any information. Not very familiar with PL/SQL, and having debug auto-generated PL/SQL code at that!

Comment: That's not PL/SQL, its just SQL.

Comment: Gotcha - I just assumed it was PL/SQL since the environment is Oracle, and I'm not familiar with what aspects of the language would call out PL/SQL as PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use the "old" Oracle's outer join operator `(+)`; Oracle supports `JOIN`s since version 9i (unless I'm wrong), and that's quite a long ago.

I didn't understand what you want to get as a result, but - it makes a difference whether you put that condition into the join, or apply it as a filter in `where` clause.

If you know Scott's sample schema, `dept` table contains department 40 while no employees in `emp` table work in that department. Therefore, it can be used to illustrate what you are asking. Compare the following queries:

Here, `deptno = 40` is part of the `JOIN`:

```
SQL> select d.deptno, d.dname, e.ename
  2  from dept d left join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno and d.deptno = 40
  3  order by d.deptno, e.ename;

    DEPTNO DNAME          ENAME
---------- -------------- ----------
        10 ACCOUNTING
        20 RESEARCH
        30 SALES
        40 OPERATIONS
```

In another example, `deptno = 40` is in `where` clause and is used as a filter:

```
SQL> select d.deptno, d.dname, e.ename
  2  from dept d left join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno
  3  where d.deptno = 40
  4  order by d.deptno, e.ename;

    DEPTNO DNAME          ENAME
---------- -------------- ----------
        40 OPERATIONS

SQL>
```

As I said: I don't know which option you want, but I hope that those examples will help you decide whether you need the 1st or the 2nd query.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I do realize that the (+) is very old syntax. Humor me for a moment (I'm not really working in a flexible querying environment) - if that was all I could do, then is my syntax such that I'm truly achieving a left join? I think so, but let me recount what my concern is. In this "left join tbl1.ID = tbl2.ID(+) and tbl2.col2 = 12345" I'm specifying two conditions. One is that tbl1.ID be equal to tbl2.ID, and there I am specifying a left join. The other condition is that tbl2.col2 = 12345 - I understand the difference between having a condition in the where clause vs.

Comment: join clause, what I'm really after is whether the second condition is still a left join or is it an inner join? I ask because I've seen dialects where each additional condition has to be specified as left, hence my wondering whether I'd have to do something like tbl2.col2 = 12345(+) (left joining on this condition as well as the first condition). I hope that makes more sense, if not I'll try to create a more robust example. I would test it myself in my environment, but as I've said else the environment I'm working in is pretty restrictive and difficult to work with. Thanks for your time!